# Split main class into different files

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I just finished my first application for Mac, and now works fine. The application has a main class of NSObject. This class has become huge, because I have many for loops and if-else statements. Since these cycles are repeated several times I wanted to know if you can put them in a separate class and call the point of the main class were i need them. But these cycles using variables defined in the main class. I'm a newbie and I would need a simple solution to understand and execute. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a general, it is not only for mac or objective programming BTW. Well, there are couple of ways by which you can tackle this situation for example, You can return the values for variable in new fragmented class's method and assign it in the main class. Or the common way is to use reference of your constructor.